# When can we arrive at a border but not cross it?

Tags: consciousness, space, infinite

Does that mathematisation of consciousness allow us to think of arriving at a limit but not crossing (some things seem to suggest we do *not* cross borders we *do* get to)? Is that the case only for some sorts of movement? If so, what movements can?

Does it make any difference if we think of that movement being pushed to that limit, or recreated at that limit, etc.?

Comment: You can't travel past the speed of light (physical limitation), but you can increase the speed of light in your formulae (mathematical limitation). Mathematical borders are precise, but ideal. Physical objects have subjective boundaries, which can't be overcome in multiple cases.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the relevance of "the mathematisation of consciousness" to the question of border-crossing? Are you thinking of mental borders of some kind, or only about Zeno style questions about whether moving objects can cross some spatial borders, or some other type of border?